# How to display NDEF message after NDEF discovered/activity launched?

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare

Have read through a number of questions similar to mine - I can only apologise if I have missed the solution to my woes, but I really can't work this out!

I have managed to get my nfc activity working - tapping the tag launches the correct activity of my app - but the ndef message is not displayed and I can't figure out why...

The tag is a Mifare Ultralight with a Plain Text message encoded. (mimetype: plain/text)

Here's my code, thank you all for your help, this forum should have a 'donate a beer' button!

```
package com.example.prototype02;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class nfcActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "NFCReadTag";
    private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    private IntentFilter[] mNdefExchangeFilters;
    private PendingIntent mNfcPendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nfclayout);

        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        mNfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
                getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP), 0);


        IntentFilter nfcIntent = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        nfcIntent.addDataScheme("text/plain");      
        mNdefExchangeFilters = new IntentFilter[] { nfcIntent };

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mNfcAdapter != null) mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);      
        if (mNfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            NdefMessage[] messages = null;
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(mNfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                messages = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }}
                else if (rawMsgs == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No NDEF Message Read", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            if(messages[0] != null) {
                String result="";
                byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
                for (int b = 1; b<payload.length; b++) { // skip SOH
                    result += (char) payload[b];
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Safe Location Registered - " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Intent Error...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I've published some template activites here: http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your activity is started by the NFC intent, then `onNewIntent()` will not be called (it will only be called when you scan the tag when the activity is already in the foreground). Try doing something like calling `onNewIntent(getIntent())` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thank you so much - man apologies for the delayed response. This solved my problem, bar one (new) issue...Now the NDEF Message is displayed, except for the very first character of the message...I have checked the tag in another nfc reading app and have verified the first char is there. Any ideas would be much appreciated! Am sure I'm missing the obvious.

Comment: Thank you! Again - so sorry for delay - I hadn't seen your comment re Arrays - silly typing error :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: (taken from StickyNotes NFC sample)

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mResumed = true;
    // Sticky notes received from Android
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        NdefMessage[] messages = getNdefMessages(getIntent());
        byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
        setNoteBody(new String(payload));
        setIntent(new Intent()); // Consume this intent.
    }
    enableNdefExchangeMode();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mResumed = false;
    mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundNdefPush(this);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // NDEF exchange mode
    if (!mWriteMode && NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        NdefMessage[] msgs = getNdefMessages(intent);
        promptForContent(msgs[0]);
    }

    // Tag writing mode
    if (mWriteMode && NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Tag detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        writeTag(getNoteAsNdef(), detectedTag);
    }
}
```